# I am trying to make three dice roll simultaneously until they land on the same number

Tags: java

I am trying to make my program be able to show the count of how many times it takes until 3 dice land on the same number and then tell the use how many times it took, the number that it had landed on and have them repeat this process 3 times. However, I can't figure out how to make the program work. Currently, only Try, Dice 1, Dice 2, Dice 3 pop up, and then the amount of rolls it took under Try. How do I make the rest of this program work? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Q1
  {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random g=new Random();
    boolean same=false;
    int dice1=0;
    int dice2=0;
    int dice3=0;
    int count=0;
    System.out.println("Try\tDice 1\tDice 2\tDice 3");
    do{
            System.out.println();
            count++;
            dice1=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            dice2=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            dice3=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            System.out.print(count+"\t");

            if(dice1==dice2 && dice2==dice3){
            same=true;
            System.out.println("It took"+count+"times and they all landed on number "+??);
           }
       }
       while(!same);
    }
}
```

Comment: You initialize same to `true`.  So whether or not the dice are the same, it's still `true`, so you only ever loop once.

Comment: now that I made it false, the count works, however the output of the dice still isn't showing. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`same` will always be true because you never set it to false in your code, yet in your do-while loop you're checking for `!same`, which will always return false since same is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Q1
  {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random g=new Random();
    boolean same=false;
    int dice1=0;
    int dice2=0;
    int dice3=0;
    int count=0;
    System.out.println("Try\tDice 1\tDice 2\tDice 3");
    do{
            System.out.println();
            count++;
            dice1=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            dice2=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            dice3=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            System.out.print(count+"\t");

            if(dice1==dice2 && dice2==dice3){
            same=true;
            System.out.println("It took"+count+"times.");
           }
       }
       while(!same);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you got the count to work, but unfortunately the output of the dice (1-6) still isn't showing.